# How to create a Google Container Registry permanent token?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-pipelines, google-container-registry

I need to setup a CI/CD pipeline with gcr.io as my container registry.

I use a Service Connection with the Docker ID `_token` and password from `gcloud auth print-access-token` to connect my pipeline agent to the registry.

However this token is short-lived. 
How can I create a permanent token ? Does gcr.io allow that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of authentication options presented on https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication. They tend to emphasize short-lived access, because otherwise:

- a malicious pull request could push containers to GCR
- someone accessing the CI environment could run commands with access
- someone accessing the CI environment could extract that permanent token and reuse it

If your goal in using a "permanent token" is performance related, there are many other areas to try boosting efficiency that are safer.

If you are already using the [Access Token](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#access_token) mechanism, you probably already have service account keys in your CI environment. If that service account has access to the container registry, you can use  the [JSON Key File](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file) authentication mechanism for a more "permanent" access.

Any privileges associated with this service account are at risk of leak to anyone that can copy the service account key out of the CI system. I like to base64 encode keys in CI to minimize the chance of accidentally display, though this does very little to deter deliberate theft.